# (Spritekit) iPad resolution not 1024x768?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm trying to set a background texture and I want it to cover the entire screen.

I prepared the background files exactly to size in photoshop before hand. There are 2 files in my project:

1. background.png - 1024x768px
2. background@2x.png - 2048x1536px

I am running the following code:

```
SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"background"];

SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture];
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
background.size = CGSizeMake(750, 550);

[self addChild:background];
```

And it is giving me this result http://d.pr/i/Ej2m - notice that the entire screen is almost filled and the background size is `background.size = CGSizeMake(750, 550)`. Why is this?

Comment: If you have made the texture with the desired size then you do not need to set the background.size.

Comment: I wonder, what did you expect would happen by changing the sprite's size?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D If the resolution of an iPad is 1024x768, why does 750x550px sprite fill the screen? see screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You manually changed the sprite's size:

```
background.size = CGSizeMake(750, 550);
```

So it will display in a smaller region (750x550) than its original size (1024x768). Allow me to say: d'uh! ;)

Comment: Why does a sprite sized to 750x550 fill the entire screen of an ipad which should be 1024x768? (See screenshot)